# How to debug the ASP.NET MVC code in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, debugging

I am using C# on .NET

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022
Version 17.7.4
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.7.4+34031.279
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.09032

Installed Version: Community

ASP.NET and Web Tools   17.7.273.65229
ASP.NET and Web Tools

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   17.7.273.65229
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   17.7.273.65229
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools

C# Tools   4.7.0-3.23416.8+43b0b05cc4f492fd5de00f6f6717409091df8daa
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Cookiecutter   17.0.23189.3
Provides tools for finding, instantiating and customizing templates in cookiecutter format.

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

NuGet Package Manager   6.7.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/

Python - Profiling support   17.0.23189.3
Profiling support for Python projects.

Python with Pylance   17.0.23189.3
Provides IntelliSense, projects, templates, debugging, interactive windows, and other support for Python developers.

Razor (ASP.NET Core)   17.7.3.2333001+0ab18affdf2a37647768d0e25f5f021bee6257a1
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.

SQL Server Data Tools   17.7.10.1
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

TypeScript Tools   17.0.20829.2001
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   4.7.0-3.23416.8+43b0b05cc4f492fd5de00f6f6717409091df8daa
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual F# Tools   17.7.0-beta.23314.10+e612cf93b989503c89e3a5830090062b7ab5e143
Microsoft Visual F# Tools

Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2
AI-assisted development for Visual Studio.
```

I know how to work on .NET forms.

I have ASP.NET MVC code (I am not the developer) to trace and fix but it is my first time working with ASP.NET MVC.

Every time I try to add a breakpoint in my code, it gets "not be hit"

[image]

I was sure that it was in debug mode

[image]

but still, nothing makes the code debug

Any idea why is this happening and how to debug it?

Comment: How are you running it? Just hitting F5?

Comment: VS is giving you the problem: `No Symbols have been loaded...`. Check your project build for what type of build symbols are produced. Just because it's in `Debug` configuration doesn't mean it's producing symbols.

Comment: @Alex yes i hit the run button

Comment: @LightningRider how can i fix that?

Comment: @asmgx, it depends on your project file. For SDK style project: right click your project, then click properties, select Build -> General on the left then check what Debug symbols has (anything other than `no symbols` should be fine). For old projects, Right click your project and click properties, Select Build, Click Advanced, make sure Debugging information isn't set to `None`.

Comment: @JackJJun yes i did and still cannot debug

Comment: @asmgx, Sorry for the late response, I want to know which step you meet the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the Microsoft Learning [Debug ASP.NET apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-enable-debugging-for-aspnet-applications?view=vs-2022#debug-aspnet-apps) to know how to debug the ASP.NET MVC code in Visual Studio 2022.
Here are my detailed steps.

First, I created a ASP.NET MVC app.

[image]

Second, I write some code and put a breakpoint.

[image]

Third, Please press F5 to run the mvc project

Fourth, Please click Contact to trigger the breakpoint

[image]

Finally, you could see the breakpoint can be debugged.

[image]